# Making a route a private and not accessible through URLs

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to implement a `URL Redirect` to redirect all request to a url for e.g. like `www.myweb.com/201` to `www.myweb.com/201/my-blog-title`:

The code I have is like this:

`In controller:`

```
    public ActionResult PostUrlDetermine(int pId)
    {
            ...
            TempData["postInfo"] = postInfo[];
            if (postInfo != null)
            {
            int urlTitleLength = 50;
            string urlPostTitle = "";
            if (postInfo[1].Length > urlTitleLength)
                urlPostTitle = postInfo[1].Substring(0, urlTitleLength);
            else
                urlPostTitle = postInfo[1];
            urlPostTitle = urlPostTitle.Replace(' ', '-');
            return RedirectToAction("Post", new { pId = pId, postTitle = urlPostTitle });
        }
        else if (postInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToRoute("Blog");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Post", new { pId = pId });
    }

    public ActionResult Post(int pId, string postTitle)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

`Route.config`

```
   routes.MapRoute("PostUrlDetermine", "{pId}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "PostUrlDetermine", }, new { pId = @"^\d{1,3}$" });
   routes.MapRoute(name: "Post", url: "{pId}/{postTitle}", defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post", postTitle = UrlParameter.Optional}, constraints: new { pId = @"^\d{1,3}$" });
```

The above code works fine when the URL only contain ID `www.myweb.com/201` as its picksup the `PostUrlDetermine` route and direct it towards the action and all. but when URL also contain the title like `www.myweb.com/201/my-blog-title` it directly hits the `Post` route which send the view without fetching the info.

I want both URLs to go for `PostUrlDetermine` route.

Is there a way i can declare a particular route only accessible from inside and not applicable to urls?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to get to. What is the purpose of all these?

Comment: to implements a route that `www.myweb.com/201` and `www.myweb.com/201/my-blog-title` becomes same.. just like StackOverflow `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973668` and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973668/making-a-route-a-private-and-not-accessible-through-urls` both brings you to this same page.

Comment: You should be using a 301 redirect in this case, not a 302. This might be easier to implement if you subclass RouteBase, because you can control how your URLs are constructed as well.

Comment: How can i implement a `302` redirect, can you explain plz, I am little new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both routes need to resolve to the `PostUrlDetermine` action, and do some conditional checks to see if a redirect is required.

Try the following

**Global.asax**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Post",
    "{pId}/{postTitle}",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "PostUrlDetermine", postTitle = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { pId = @"^\d{1,3}$" }
    );
```

**BlogController**

```
public ActionResult PostUrlDetermine(int pId, string postTitle)
{
    // check viewdata/postinfo
    string[] postInfo = (string[])TempData["postInfo"] ?? // get post info here;

    // no post data redirect to blog
    if (postInfo == null) 
        return RedirectToRoute("Blog");

    TempData["postInfo"] = postInfo;

    // check posttitle
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(postTitle))
    {
        int urlTitleLength = 50;
        string urlPostTitle = "";
        if (postInfo[1].Length > urlTitleLength)
            urlPostTitle = postInfo[1].Substring(0, urlTitleLength);
        else
            urlPostTitle = postInfo[1];
        urlPostTitle = urlPostTitle.Replace(' ', '-');

        // viewdata no posttitle redirect
        return RedirectToAction("PostUrlDetermine", new { pId, postTitle = urlPostTitle });
    }

    // viewdata and posttitle exist return view
    return Post();
}

public ActionResult Post()
{
    return View("Post");
}
```

This makes the `Post` action somewhat redundant so you could refactor further to just return the view directly from `PostUrlDetermine`

```
// viewdata and posttitle exist return view
return View("Post");
```

---

Update

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(postTitle) || postInfo[1].Split(' ')[0] != postTitle.Split('-')[0])
{
    ...
    // viewdata no posttitle redirect
    return RedirectToAction ...
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work for me in testing. Which `return` line are you hitting? If you are hitting the final `return RedirectToAction("Post", new { pId = pId });` then the redirect loop will continue because there is no `postTitle` defined. Presumably if you are hitting this point then the blog post doesn't exist?

Comment: as i said in the question incase of url with title like `www.myweb.com/201/my-blog-title` it directly hits the Post route which send the view without fetching the info. And i think your both routes are also defining the same thing.

Comment: My apologies, I think I misunderstood initially, I've edited my answer let me know if this helps.

Comment: Ok, it works but now the problem with this is it will work with any second parameter given for e.g. `www.myweb.com/201/my-blog-title` or `www.myweb.com/201/asklfjklasjfk` are same. However i want to redirect using correct blog title only?

Comment: You'll need to add another condition to the action to validate the `postTitle` against the `postInfo` value. See update